# Show progress of page Scrolling in a android viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to show page progress in top of a viewpager in android. The progress bar will become blue while you scrolling to next screen.

Any help??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnPageChangeListener()` method to set a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` which can listen for when you scroll the viewpager to get to another page or when you simply scroll the viewpager.

Example:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Write code to change progressbar when page is scrolled here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //Write code to change progressbar when page is changed here
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

See these references for more information.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html